# How can I make a titlepage with a twocolumn documet?

Tags: titles, two-column

I want to create a titlepage to a twocolumn document, but the two columns is also aplied to titlepage. I want the title page to be centered to the page. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{margin=4cm}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} %linha horizontal
    \center
    
    
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \textsc{\large University}\\[1.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large Subject}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\large Group X | Turma Y}\\[0.5cm]

    \HRule\\[0.4cm]
    {\huge\bfseries this is the title}\\[0.4cm]
    \HRule\\[0.4cm]

    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \large
        \;\,\textit{Autores}\\[1ex]
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    alumn & 0000 \\
                    alumn & 0000 \\
                    alumn & 0000 \\
                    alumn & 0000
                \end{tabular}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
        ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \large
            \textit{Docentes}\\
                blabla\\
                blabla\\
                blabla\\
                blabla
    
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill\vfill\vfill

    {\large\today}

    \vfill

    \restoregeometry
\end{titlepage}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` to switch to one column for the title then back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is minimally modified from your code, but note that it is not a great idea to add spacing in the way you're doing it. Also, if you change fontsize and then don't end the paragraph, things like line spacing go haywire.

But for your actual question, you can use `titling`'s `titlingpage` environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} %linha horizontal

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
  \begin{center}

    \vspace*{1cm}
    \textsc{\large University}\\[1.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large Subject}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\large Group X | Turma Y}\\[0.5cm]
    
    \HRule\\[0.4cm]
    {\huge\bfseries this is the title}\\[0.4cm]
    \HRule\\[0.4cm]
    
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{flushleft}
        \large
        \;\,\textit{Autores}\\[1ex]
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
          alumn & 0000 \\
          alumn & 0000 \\
          alumn & 0000 \\
          alumn & 0000
        \end{tabular}
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{flushright}
        \large
        \textit{Docentes}\\
        blabla\\
        blabla\\
        blabla\\
        blabla
        
      \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \vfill\vfill\vfill
    
    {\large\today}
    
    \vfill
  \end{center}

\end{titlingpage}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image: single column titlingpage followed by double column body]